# SublimeText - Ubuntu 14.04 (Radeon 8650) - Very slow performance

Tags: graphics-card, sublime-text-2, fglrx

I've been using Sublime for a couple of years now and it's been fine until a couple of days back, when I upgraded to **Ubuntu 14.04 on a AMD APU A10** machine. I was using 12.04 on a Core i3 processor till then.

My Configuration is:
**AMD APU 10 - AMD Radeon HD 8650G 2.5 GB Dual Graphics.

8 GB of Ram and 1TB HDD.**

I use my laptop's display which is 1366x768 and a monitor which is 1920x1080. Everything worked fine with the old laptop, but in the new one, when I **drag and select text the latency is incredibly high**. The **scrolling** of a 500 line file is also very sluggish and I am not able to experience the smoothness I was used to with Sublime.

I have the proprietary Catalyst driver - **fblrx v14.10** which seems to be the latest one.

I am having a major productivity loss. Can anyone help me out here?

Btw, I tried fgl_glxgears and the fps is ~ 800 on the laptop screen and 400 on the larger screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The AMD proprietary driver is good only for 3D rendering. When it comes to 2D, the overall performance is quite poor.

However, if you install the open source driver, it is the opposite: 2D is far better, 3D performance are a mess.

Comment: Oh so the stuff on things like Sublime n all is 2D graphics? Are you suggesting me to switch to the OpenSource driver? Is my cart supported? Thanks

Comment: I'm not 100% sure for APU, but if there is any open source driver, you should be able to see it in settings > software & update > Additionnal drivers (or desactivate the proprietary one if activated).

I'm pretty sure that sublime is using a lot of 2D ressources since it's a really polished UI.

Comment: Or they is another way by console:

http://linuxg.net/how-to-properly-remove-the-proprietary-ati-drivers-on-debian-ubuntu-and-linux-mint/

Answer (score 8):

Try changing scrolling speed setting to -.

```
"scroll_speed": 0,
```